# Решение олимпиадной задачи "Межрегиональная олимпиада"

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, динамические-массивы, олимпиада

Есть задача на динамическое программирование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для решения задачи я написал код на C++ 11:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<tuple>

using namespace std;

struct problem {
    int startTime, solvingTime, endTime, score, index;
};

bool sort_problems_by_endtime(problem a, problem b) {
    return a.endTime < b.endTime;
}

tuple<int, vector<int>> maxScore(vector<problem> problems) {
    sort(problems.begin(), problems.end(), sort_problems_by_endtime); // сортируем задачи по времени окончания их решения

    vector<int> links(problems.size());
    vector<long> problems_optimal(problems.size()); // создаем динамический массив, хранящий оптимальные решения,
                                                    // где problems_optimal[i] - это максимальное кол-во баллов, которое возможно получить,
                                                    // используюя только первые i задач
    problems_optimal[0] = 0; 

    int j = 0;  // j хранит индекс последней задачи, которая заканчивается не позже чем начинается задача i
    problems[j].endTime = 0;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < problems_optimal.size(); i ++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            j = 0;
        }
        else {
            for (; j < i; j ++) {
                if (problems[j].endTime > problems[i].startTime) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            j --;
        } // вычисляем j методом двойных указателей
                                                // выясняем что лучше: решать или не решать
        problems_optimal[i] = max(problems_optimal[i - 1], problems_optimal[j] + problems[i].score); 

        if (problems_optimal[i - 1] > problems_optimal[j] + problems[i].score) { // создаем ссылку
            links[i] = -1;
        }
        else {
            links[i] = j;
        }
    }

    vector<int> moves;
    for (int i = problems_optimal.size() - 1; i != 0;) { // восстанавливаем решение (т. е. извлекаем ход решения задач)
        if (links[i] == -1) {
            i --;
        }
        else {
            moves.push_back(problems[i].index);
            i = links[i];
        }
    }

    return make_tuple(problems_optimal[problems_optimal.size() - 1], moves); // возвращаем оптимальное кол-во очков и массив с ходом решения
}


int main() {
    int k;

    cin >> k;
    vector<problem> problems(k + 1); // создаем динамический массив с задачами, причём нумеровать будем с единицы, чтобы не запутаться

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i ++) {
        cin >> problems[i].startTime >> problems[i].solvingTime >> problems[i].score;

        problems[i].endTime = problems[i].startTime + problems[i].solvingTime; // высчитываем время конца решения задачи

        problems[i].index = i; // так как дальше массив с задачами будет отсортирован, нам необходимо запомнить начальные положения задач
    }

    cout << get<0>(maxScore(problems)) << endl;

    vector<int> moves = get<1>(maxScore(problems));

    cout << moves.size() << endl;

    for (int i = moves.size() - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
        cout << moves[i] << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа проходит лишь 4 из 50 тестов. Я не могу понять в чём проблема. Проверял на нескольких простых примерах, как своих, так и взятых из условия, работало правильно. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Неверный алгоритм - очевидно же. Разбираться надо глубже. Проблемы могут возникнуть на каких-то специфических значениях входных данных из-за того, что программист не учел переполнение переменных, неправильно указал модификаторы ввода-вывода. Иногда бывает, если используется рекурсия, что стека не хватает.

Comment: Но, как правило, в алгоритме есть серьезный дефект. Например, программа решается методом динамического программирования (перебор с сохранением результата), а вы пытаетесь применить "жадный алгоритм". В частности кейсов последний дает оптимальное решение, а в части - нет (утыкаетесь в локальный минимум некоей функции)

Comment: @DeathCookies напишите лучше идею как вы хотели сделать. Я подскажу можно так сделать или нет, просто если бага в коде то одно а если в логике то другое.

Comment: @pavel Идея заключается в заполнении массива следующим образом: сначала мы отсортировываем массив с задачами по времени окончания их решения (т.е. время выдачи + время, необходимое на решение). Затем заполняем новый массив следующим образом: m[0] = 0; m[i] = max(m[i - 1], m[j] + v[i]); (т. е. берем либо результат без решения i-той задачи, либо с ёё решением, учитывая то, что до её решения может быть решена лишь задача j (т. е. последняя задача, которая заканчивается раньше чем i-ая)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общая идея. Пусть мы взялись решать задачу `U` со временем `Tu` тогда нам нужно максимизировать сумму `solve(0,Tu) + Cu + solve(Tu+Su,inf)`. Уже видно что это ДП - наивное решение - перебирать первую задачу, которую мы будем решать.

Я бы решал так: переберём последнюю задачу которую мы будем решать `0..N`, потом вычислим результат для неё. Но это всё  не успеет по времени поэтому дерево (пойдёт даже фенвика, но помните про память!).

Псевдокод (задачи уже отсортированны по времени начала):

```
for (last_task = 0; last_task < N; last_task ++){
     Tree.update(T[last_task] + S[last_task], 
                 Tree.max(0,T[last_task]) + C[last_task] );
}
cout << Tree.max(0, MAX_INT) << endl;
```

Восстановить ответ уже не проблема. Для этого нужно чуть изменить дерево чтобы узнавать не только значение но и номер + позицию максимального элемента.
Пусть дерево возвращает `{value,time, position}`. Тогда:

```
vector<int> ans;
int MaxTime = MAX_INT;
while (true){
    auto tmp = Tree.getFullMax(0,MaxTime);
    if (tmp.value == 0) break; 
    ans.push_back(tmp.position);
    MaxTime = tmp.time;
}  
cout << ans.size()<<endl;
for (int i=ans.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
      cout << ans[i]<<" ";
```

Можно и без дерева примерно так:

```
struct Task{
   int t,s,c,n;
};

Task task[100000];
long long bestSum[100010];
int goSum[100010];

bool cmp(Task a, Task b){
   return a.t + a.s < b.t + b.s;
}

int main() {
   freopen("olympiad.in","r",stdin);
   freopen("olympiad.out","w",stdout);
   int N;
   cin >> N;
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
      cin >> task[i].t >> task[i].s >> task[i].c;
      task[i].n = i+1;
   }
   sort(task,task + N, cmp);
   bestSum[0] = 0;
   Task empt;
   empt.s = 0;
   empt.c = 0;
   empt.n = 0;
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
      bestSum[i + 1] = bestSum[i];
        goSum[i + 1] = -1;
      empt.t = task[i].t;
      int prev = upper_bound(task,task+N,empt,cmp) - task;
      long long nn = bestSum[prev] + task[i].c;
      if (nn > bestSum[i + 1]){
        goSum[i + 1] = prev;
        bestSum[i + 1] = nn;
      }
   }
   cout << bestSum[N]<<endl;
   vector<int> ans;
   while (N)
     if (goSum[N] == -1)
          N--;
     else {
          ans.push_back(task[N-1].n);
          N = goSum[N]; 
      } 
   cout << ans.size() << endl;
   for (int i=ans.size() -1; i>=0; i--)
       cout << ans[i]<< " ";
   cout << endl;
}
```

Так что идея в автора в целом реализуема...

Comment: Нет, моя программа выдаёт правильный ответ. То есть на вход:

3 
1 10 100
3 10 1
15 1 1

На выходе 
101
2
1 3

Comment: дело еще и в том, что программа проваливает тесты не из-за превышения лимита времени, а из-за неправильного ответа. Попробуй накинуть пару примеров, на которых моя программа провалится. Буду ну очень благодарен.

Comment: https://contest.yandex.ru/roiarchive/contest/2010/problems/3/

Comment: @DeathCookies вот полное решение без дерева. Теперь можно и сравнивать.

Comment: яндекс принял решение?

Comment: @DeathCookies да.

Comment: единственное, что я не понял - это как работает вот эта строчка кода:  int prev = upper_bound(task,task+N,empt,cmp) - task;

Comment: так как она работает?

Comment: @DeathCookies это бинарный поиск (дихотомия) вы использовали скользящее окно но на асимптотику это не влияет. Фактически возвращает указатель на первый элемент больше заданного последним параметром.